# I want to create a Folder/file using function in jsTree

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I want to create a new file/folder in jstree using javascript function 
like

```
function create_new_node(...){
// this is external function 
// append to current selected node in the tree ( I have it ).
//... etc
}
```

the jstree script :

```
$('#tree').jstree(..) 
.on('create_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
    console.log("create_node.jstree",data);

//this trigger when item created
  })
});
```

How I can do that ... ?

Comment: Вo you want create file or folder on server or on users computer?

Comment: @newman , no I want to create folder in the jstree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
    $('#tree').jstree("create_node", "parent_id", function(e,data){
    console.log('hi', data);
});
```